# Can I user OpenDaylight to query a network node via JSON RPC?

Tags: json, unit-testing, testing, curl, opendaylight

I'm new to OpenDaylight and I'd like get some advice or simple usage examples. My purpose is to test a remote network device.

Before OpenDaylight, I started by sending JSON RPC queries via CURL commands from the Linux shell and scripts.